# How to post a video to Facebook using FB.api Javascript SDK?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to post a video to a facebook user's timeline by following [Video Creation Graph API end point documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video/#Creating). Before posting to Graph API, I sign in a user using [FB.login()](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v8.0). I ask the user to grant `public_profile`, `email`, and [`user_videos`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference/user_videos) permissions to my facebook application. A user signs in successfully and an access token is returned. I also receive `user_videos,email,public_profile` in `grantedScopes` section in the `FB.login()` callback response.

However, when I make an `FB.api()` request to post a video to user timeline, I see this error:

```js
window.FB.api(
  `${authResponse.userID}/videos`,
  'POST',
  {
    file_url: <video-url>,
    access_token: authResponse.accessToken,
  },
  (response) => {
    console.log(response)
  }
)
```

```js
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) No permission to publish the video",
     "type": "OAuthException",
     "code": 100,
     "fbtrace_id": "whatever"
  }
}
```

A few things to note are:

### Application review warning on login dialog:

When the Facebook login dialog is displayed to the user, a warning is displayed on top:

`Submit APP-NAME for Login Review Some of the permissions below have not been approved for use by Facebook. Submit for review now or learn more.`

I am using [Test Version](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps/) of my application to develop this feature. Moreover, I am using the admin user of the facebook application to test this integration. I don't understand why above warning is displayed. Do I really need to submit my application for review while I am in the process of integrating this feature?

### Disallowed posting to facebook

Another warning: `This doesn't let the app post to Facebook` is displayed on the login dialog. As far as I know, the `user_videos` permission should let my application post videos to a user's timeline. But the displayed warning is contradictory to my assumption. Do I need to ask some additional permissions before I can post videos to user timeline?

### HTTPS errors because of development on localhost

I see errors related to non-availability of an HTTPS domain in my browser developer console when integrating application on localhost.

```
The method FB.getLoginStatus can no longer be called from http pages.
The method FB.login can no longer be called from http pages.
The method FB.api can no longer be called from http pages.
```

Do I need to implement https for my local development setup before I can carry out this integration?

### Posting to graph-video.facebook.com

I am confused with the [Video Publishing documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/video-api/guides/publishing). It says that I need to make a `POST` request to `https://graph-video.facebook.com` instead of `https://graph.facebook.com` in order to publish a video. The same documentation also mentions that, "Publishing on Users is not supported". This is contradictory to [Video Creation documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video/#Creating).

What exactly should I do in order to be able to post a video to facebook user timeline using `FB.api` or any other method?

Comment: I don’t think `user_videos` allows for posting of videos, only reading. `publish_video` exists, but that is only for live videos.

Comment: @CBroe The "Allowed Usages" section in `user_videos` permission does say, "Provide people with the ability to edit or create new video content using existing videos." Unless I am mistaken, the keyword "existing videos" might have a different meaning. If `user_videos` permission does not allow for posting videos, then what does?

Comment: Nothing? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/video-api/guides/publishing: _“The Video API allows you to publish Videos on Pages and Groups. Publishing on Users is not supported.”_

Comment: @CBroe That'd be contradictory to the [Video Creation Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video/#Creating). Something *does* allow creation of videos to user timeline.

Comment: The documentation sometimes is contradictory, yes. With all the changes and deprecations over time, they don’t always manage to keep everything up-to-date in all places. `publish_actions` was generally the permission needed to publish stuff in the name of a user, but that has been removed. And the only two permissions listed under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference, that are explicitly about videos, are `publish_video`, but that is for _live_ videos only, and `user_videos`, which appears to only allow read access.

Comment: *sigh* That seems to be the case. Facebook, with all its resources, still shows lackluster performance when it comes to supporting or providing up to date documentation for its application developers.

Comment: I asked this question on FB developer community forum in case someone there answers it: https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/682134762340999/

Answer (score 2):

See this page:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/videos/

> You can make a POST request to videos edge from the following paths:
> /{user_id}/videos

**Try this:**

```
/* make the API call */
FB.api(
    "/{user_id}/videos",
    "POST",
    {
        "source": "{video-data}"
    },
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
      }
    }
);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I have tried. Both with `source` and `file_url` parameters but I still get the error mentioned in the question.